# Admin privileges for users authenticated to a Django site with social-auth-app-django against Auth0

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, auth0, python-social-auth

I've got a *Django site* with authentication handled by **[Auth0](https://auth0.com)** (following [this quickstart guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/django)). The issue I have is that users logged in don't have access to Django Admin section:

[image: Django Admin Login Error]

How can I assign certain Auth0-authenticated users the privileges to login Admin? Somehow link them with current Django-based users perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Auth0 roles, or extra data.

The flow works like this:

1. Log into Auth0 and add in roles or extra data to your user
2. Create a Django backend in your authentication pipeline to read in the roles/extra data infomration
3. Have your backend will check this role information and add set "is_staff" to True for the user